# Format Excel chart: white title on blue background, data point labels on coloured circles of size proportional to value

Tags: excel, excel-charts

How do I recreate the following chart/image?

I don't know how to create a border with the padded header etc.

[image]

Comment: thanks for cleaning the question up. It's important to note that I have my excel chart - so the question is how to create the borders etc in the same style. Thanks!

Comment: Well, yeah, making an Excel chart is trivial; formatting like you want it is the real problem. Browse [Jon Peltier's site](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/ChartIndex.html); surely you'll find bits and pieces to help you make the various elements of your chart.

Comment: so far, I've made a smartart box, styled it as best I can - and combined this with the excel chart. Kinda looks similar. Was just wanting to check if there was something obvious that I might be missing...

Comment: BTW This is not a question for stackoverflow. Ask on superuser.com instead. I may have a shot at it there.

Comment: Rough sketch: http://i.imgur.com/Qh2fuQS.png

Comment: Of course, the fancy border and header are examples of gratuitous formatting. A plain text title using the same blue color as the rounded rectangle in the sample will look good on a chart without a border.